# batch or perl reshaping a txt file

Tags: perl, text, batch-file

I would like to write a script that reshapes a text file that looks like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4

word5
word6
word7
word8

word9
word10
word11
word12
...
```

into this:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 word6 word7 word8
word9 word10 word11 word12
...
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i.bak -pwe 's/\S\s*\K\n$/ /' input.txt
```

- `-i.bak`  saves a backup in `input.txt.bak`
- `-p`  puts a while (<>) loop around your script
- The regex looks for a line that ends with a non-whitespace character
  not followed by whitespace, followed by newline and replaces the
  newline with a space. The `\K` escape means "keep anything before this".

Another option:

```
perl -i.bak -lpwe 'BEGIN { $/="" }; s/\n/ /g' input.txt
```

Using paragraph mode in the BEGIN block, and following each print with a newline with `-l`

Comment: This is the first time I see the `\K` flag in action. This does away with the need of a variable-length-lookbehind

Comment: @Zaid It is mentioned in the same place as lookbehind http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions

Comment: Nice. As with so many Perl features, this little nugget is very useful to know

Comment: @Zaid Makes me wonder why variable length lookbehind is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -l -00 -aF/\s*\n\s*/ -ne 'print "@F"' /source/file > /dest/file
```

Explanation (using TLP's suggestions)

- **-l:** auto-chomp records and makes `print` act like `say`.
- **-00:** puts perl into "paragraph mode" and it looks for successive "\n\n"
- **-a:** auto-split records into fields array `@F`
- **-F:** use the following pattern to split the record (using auto-split).
- **-ne:** execute the following for each record (delimited by "\n\n"), only print when told

Comment: a readable script which isn't a long command line would be nice :)

Comment: `-l` not only chomps input, it also adds a newline to `print`. Also, might as well check out `-a` and `-F`. ;)

Comment: TLP's right, there's no need for `say` if `-l` is already there

Comment: It's an interesting solution. I did not realise `-00` was paragraph mode, but it must do something else as well, because `-00 -lpwe 's/\n/ /g'` does not give the same result as `-lpwe 'BEGIN { $/ = "" }; s/\n/ /g;'`.

Comment: It seems that `perl -l -00` gives the correct result, but `perl -00 -l` adds an extra newline. Which would imply that `-l` *adds* to the existing `$\ ` instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @TLP the `-0` flag might be setting *both* input and output?

Comment: From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*[_octnum_]): `If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/ `. Which would mean that `-00` sets `$/` to `""`, but the `-l` option interprets this as `"\n\n"`. A little perl magic, bordering on obscure.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your groups are "paragraphs" so read them as such; split the words on whitespace; rejoin them using a single space (blank) and print the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
local $/ = '';
my @words;
while (<DATA>) {
    @words = split;
    print join q( ), @words, "\n";
    @words = ();
}
__DATA__
word1
word2
word3
word4

word5
word6
word7
word8

word9
word10
word11
word12
```

Comment: Will not work for lines that contain whitespace. E.g. "word1 word2\n...".

Comment: Well, it *will* work, but it will replace any whitespace with space, better to split on `\n` specifically.